# What parameters I can pass to this function?

Tags: delphi, rotation, shapes

I found a [function](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=1199)

```
 function RotateBitmap(var hDIB: HGlobal;
 radang: Double; clrBack: TColor): Boolean;
```

that rotates an image. But I don't know how to call this function. What parameters I can pass to this function.
I don't know how to use this func at all.

Comment: Thanx David. Firstly I don't know this parameter: `hDIB: HGlobal`.

Comment: It sounds like a handle to a DIB. But the code does GlobalLock on it and interprets it as a pointer to bitmap info header. That seems plain odd to me. I'd look for another routine. Have you tried graphics32 yet? I'm sure it will do this, and in a very natural Delphi way.

Comment: that code works with DIB section handle, not TBitmap. You have to call GetObject first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the code presented `hDIB` is a pointer to a single memory block containing 2 structures - BitmapInfo and bitmap's pixel array. You can obtain these structures from `TBitmap` using [`GetDIBSizes`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Graphics.GetDIBSizes) and [`GetDIB`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Graphics.GetDIB) functions.

If you are interested in bitmap transformations you can follow David's advice and try [graphics32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/graphics32/)