# Rotate bitmap by real angle

Tags: delphi, image-processing, rotation

Once upon a time, reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7690388/757830), I wondered how to rotate a bitmap by any degree without fiddling around with all the bits myself. Recently, [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10464410/757830) had obvious difficulties with it too.

There are already many questions dealing with rotation at 90° intervals, most notabaly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/848025/757830), but I want to rotate by a real angle. Preferably with the possibility to adjust the image size due to the rotation, and with setting a custom (transparent) background color for the parts that will be added to image surface. I then suppose the signature of the routine would look something like:

```
procedure RotateBitmap(Bmp: TBitmap; Angle: Single; AdjustSize: Boolean; 
  BackColor: TColor);
```

[These answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2270110/757830) mention the following candidates for constructing this routine: SetWorldTransform, PlgBlt, GDI+, but I would like to see an (efficient) implementation.

Comment: You might use title like *Rotate bitmap by real angle, anniversary edition* :-)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> **tl;dr;** Use GDI+

#### SetWorldTransform

With WinAPI's [SetWorldTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145104(v=vs.85).aspx) you can transform the space of device context: rotate, shear, offset, and scale. This is done by setting the members of a transform matrix of type XFORM. Fill its members according [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145228(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
procedure RotateBitmap(Bmp: TBitmap; Rads: Single; AdjustSize: Boolean;
  BkColor: TColor = clNone);
var
  C: Single;
  S: Single;
  XForm: tagXFORM;
  Tmp: TBitmap;
begin
  C := Cos(Rads);
  S := Sin(Rads);
  XForm.eM11 := C;
  XForm.eM12 := S;
  XForm.eM21 := -S;
  XForm.eM22 := C;
  Tmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Tmp.TransparentColor := Bmp.TransparentColor;
    Tmp.TransparentMode := Bmp.TransparentMode;
    Tmp.Transparent := Bmp.Transparent;
    Tmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := BkColor;
    if AdjustSize then
    begin
      Tmp.Width := Round(Bmp.Width * Abs(C) + Bmp.Height * Abs(S));
      Tmp.Height := Round(Bmp.Width * Abs(S) + Bmp.Height * Abs(C));
      XForm.eDx := (Tmp.Width - Bmp.Width * C + Bmp.Height * S) / 2;
      XForm.eDy := (Tmp.Height - Bmp.Width * S - Bmp.Height * C) / 2;
    end
    else
    begin
      Tmp.Width := Bmp.Width;
      Tmp.Height := Bmp.Height;
      XForm.eDx := (Bmp.Width - Bmp.Width * C + Bmp.Height * S) / 2;
      XForm.eDy := (Bmp.Height - Bmp.Width * S - Bmp.Height * C) / 2;
    end;
    SetGraphicsMode(Tmp.Canvas.Handle, GM_ADVANCED);
    SetWorldTransform(Tmp.Canvas.Handle, XForm);
    BitBlt(Tmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Tmp.Width, Tmp.Height, Bmp.Canvas.Handle,
      0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    Bmp.Assign(Tmp);
  finally
    Tmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

#### PlgBlt

The [PlgBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162804(v=vs.85).aspx) function performs a bit-block transfer from the specified rectangle in the source device context to the specified parallelogram in the destination device context. Map the corner points of the source image via the `lpPoint` parameter.

```
procedure RotateBitmap(Bmp: TBitmap; Rads: Single; AdjustSize: Boolean;
  BkColor: TColor = clNone);
var
  C: Single;
  S: Single;
  Tmp: TBitmap;
  OffsetX: Single;
  OffsetY: Single;
  Points: array[0..2] of TPoint;
begin
  C := Cos(Rads);
  S := Sin(Rads);
  Tmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Tmp.TransparentColor := Bmp.TransparentColor;
    Tmp.TransparentMode := Bmp.TransparentMode;
    Tmp.Transparent := Bmp.Transparent;
    Tmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := BkColor;
    if AdjustSize then
    begin
      Tmp.Width := Round(Bmp.Width * Abs(C) + Bmp.Height * Abs(S));
      Tmp.Height := Round(Bmp.Width * Abs(S) + Bmp.Height * Abs(C));
      OffsetX := (Tmp.Width - Bmp.Width * C + Bmp.Height * S) / 2;
      OffsetY := (Tmp.Height - Bmp.Width * S - Bmp.Height * C) / 2;
    end
    else
    begin
      Tmp.Width := Bmp.Width;
      Tmp.Height := Bmp.Height;
      OffsetX := (Bmp.Width - Bmp.Width * C + Bmp.Height * S) / 2;
      OffsetY := (Bmp.Height - Bmp.Width * S - Bmp.Height * C) / 2;
    end;
    Points[0].X := Round(OffsetX);
    Points[0].Y := Round(OffsetY);
    Points[1].X := Round(OffsetX + Bmp.Width * C);
    Points[1].Y := Round(OffsetY + Bmp.Width * S);
    Points[2].X := Round(OffsetX - Bmp.Height * S);
    Points[2].Y := Round(OffsetY + Bmp.Height * C);
    PlgBlt(Tmp.Canvas.Handle, Points, Bmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Bmp.Width,
      Bmp.Height, 0, 0, 0);
    Bmp.Assign(Tmp);
  finally
    Tmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

#### Graphics32

[Graphics32](http://www.graphics32.org/wiki/) is a library especially designed for fast bitmap handling. It requires some experience to grasp its full potential, but [the documentation](http://graphics32.org/documentation/Docs/_Body.htm) as well as the provided examples should get you started.

A rotation of a `TBitmap32` image is done by transforming it by one of the many available transformation classes. The `TAffineTransformation` class is needed here. First, shift the image half its size to the upper left, then rotate, and shift the result back to the lower right, possibly using the new image dimensions.

```
uses
  GR32, GR32_Transforms;

procedure RotateBitmap(Bmp: TBitmap32; Degs: Integer; AdjustSize: Boolean;
  BkColor: TColor = clNone; Transparent: Boolean = False); overload;
var
  Tmp: TBitmap32;
  Transformation: TAffineTransformation;
begin
  Tmp := TBitmap32.Create;
  Transformation := TAffineTransformation.Create;
  try
    Transformation.BeginUpdate;
    Transformation.SrcRect := FloatRect(0, 0, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height);
    Transformation.Translate(-0.5 * Bmp.Width, -0.5 * Bmp.Height);
    Transformation.Rotate(0, 0, -Degs);
    if AdjustSize then
      with Transformation.GetTransformedBounds do
        Tmp.SetSize(Round(Right - Left), Round(Bottom - Top))
    else
      Tmp.SetSize(Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height);
    Transformation.Translate(0.5 * Tmp.Width, 0.5 * Tmp.Height);
    Transformation.EndUpdate;
    Tmp.Clear(Color32(BkColor));
    if not Transparent then
      Bmp.DrawMode := dmTransparent;
    Transform(Tmp, Bmp, Transformation);
    Bmp.Assign(Tmp);
    Bmp.OuterColor := Color32(BkColor);
    if Transparent then
      Bmp.DrawMode := dmTransparent;
  finally
    Transformation.Free;
    Tmp.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure RotateBitmap(Bmp: TBitmap; Degs: Integer; AdjustSize: Boolean;
  BkColor: TColor = clNone); overload;
var
  Tmp: TBitmap32;
  Transparent: Boolean;
begin
  Tmp := TBitmap32.Create;
  try
    Transparent := Bmp.Transparent;
    Tmp.Assign(Bmp);
    RotateBitmapGR32(Tmp, Degs, AdjustSize, BkColor, Transparent);
    Bmp.Assign(Tmp);
    if Transparent then
      Bmp.Transparent := True;
  finally
    Tmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

#### GDI+

Introduced in Windows XP, Microsoft's [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798(v=vs.85).aspx) API is more efficient then the default GDI API. For Delphi 2009 and up, the library is available [from here](http://www.bilsen.com/gdiplus/index.shtml). For older Delphi versions, the library is available [from here](http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=7).

In GDI+ the rotation is also done by a transformation matrix. Drawing works quite differently though. Create a `TGPGraphics` object and attach it to a device context with its constructor. Subsequently, drawing operations on the object are translated by the API and will be output to the destination context.

```
uses
  GDIPOBJ, GDIPAPI; // < D2009
  GdiPlus;          // >= D2009

procedure RotateBitmap(Bmp: TBitmap; Degs: Integer; AdjustSize: Boolean;
  BkColor: TColor = clNone);
var
  Tmp: TGPBitmap;
  Matrix: TGPMatrix;
  C: Single;
  S: Single;
  NewSize: TSize;
  Graphs: TGPGraphics;
  P: TGPPointF;
begin
  Tmp := TGPBitmap.Create(Bmp.Handle, Bmp.Palette);
  Matrix := TGPMatrix.Create;
  try
    Matrix.RotateAt(Degs, MakePoint(0.5 * Bmp.Width, 0.5 * Bmp.Height));
    if AdjustSize then
    begin
      C := Cos(DegToRad(Degs));
      S := Sin(DegToRad(Degs));
      NewSize.cx := Round(Bmp.Width * Abs(C) + Bmp.Height * Abs(S));
      NewSize.cy := Round(Bmp.Width * Abs(S) + Bmp.Height * Abs(C));
      Bmp.Width := NewSize.cx;
      Bmp.Height := NewSize.cy;
    end;
    Graphs := TGPGraphics.Create(Bmp.Canvas.Handle);
    try
      Graphs.Clear(ColorRefToARGB(ColorToRGB(BkColor)));
      Graphs.SetTransform(Matrix);
      Graphs.DrawImage(Tmp, (Cardinal(Bmp.Width) - Tmp.GetWidth) div 2,
        (Cardinal(Bmp.Height) - Tmp.GetHeight) div 2);
    finally
      Graphs.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Matrix.Free;
    Tmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

#### Handling transparency

The routines above preserve the transparent settings of the fead bitmap, with the exception of the Graphics32 solution which requires an additional `Transparent` parameter.

#### Performance and image quality

I wrote a test application (see full code below) to tune the performance of the various methods and to compare the resulting image quality.

The first and most important conclusion is that GDI+ uses anti-aliasing where the others do not, resulting in the best image quality. (I unsuccessfully tried to prevent anti-aliasing by setting `CompositingQuality`, `InterpolationMode`, `SmoothingMode`, and `PixelOffsetMode`, so when anti-aliasing is not preferred, do not use GDI+.)

Furthermore, the GDI+ solution is also the fastest method, by far.

[image: Test results]

```
unit RotateTestForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, ExtCtrls,
  JPEG, Math, GR32, GR32_Transforms, GDIPOBJ, GDIPAPI {, GdiPlus};

type
  TTestForm = class(TForm)
  private
    FImage: TImage;
    FOpenDialog: TOpenDialog;
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

var
  TestForm: TTestForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure RotateBitmapSWT(Bmp: TBitmap; Rads: Single; AdjustSize: Boolean;
  BkColor: TColor = clNone);
var
  C: Single;
  S: Single;
  XForm: TXForm;
  Tmp: TBitmap;
begin
  C := Cos(Rads);
  S := Sin(Rads);
  XForm.eM11 := C;
  XForm.eM12 := S;
  XForm.eM21 := -S;
  XForm.eM22 := C;
  Tmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Tmp.TransparentColor := Bmp.TransparentColor;
    Tmp.TransparentMode := Bmp.TransparentMode;
    Tmp.Transparent := Bmp.Transparent;
    Tmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := BkColor;
    if AdjustSize then
    begin
      Tmp.Width := Round(Bmp.Width * Abs(C) + Bmp.Height * Abs(S));
      Tmp.Height := Round(Bmp.Width * Abs(S) + Bmp.Height * Abs(C));
      XForm.eDx := (Tmp.Width - Bmp.Width * C + Bmp.Height * S) / 2;
      XForm.eDy := (Tmp.Height - Bmp.Width * S - Bmp.Height * C) / 2;
    end
    else
    begin
      Tmp.Width := Bmp.Width;
      Tmp.Height := Bmp.Height;
      XForm.eDx := (Bmp.Width - Bmp.Width * C + Bmp.Height * S) / 2;
      XForm.eDy := (Bmp.Height - Bmp.Width * S - Bmp.Height * C) / 2;
    end;
    SetGraphicsMode(Tmp.Canvas.Handle, GM_ADVANCED);
    SetWorldTransform(Tmp.Canvas.Handle, XForm);
    BitBlt(Tmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Tmp.Width, Tmp.Height, Bmp.Canvas.Handle,
      0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    Bmp.Assign(Tmp);
  finally
    Tmp.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure RotateBitmapPLG(Bmp: TBitmap; Rads: Single; AdjustSize: Boolean;
  BkColor: TColor = clNone);
var
  C: Single;
  S: Single;
  Tmp: TBitmap;
  OffsetX: Single;
  OffsetY: Single;
  Points: array[0..2] of TPoint;
begin
  C := Cos(Rads);
  S := Sin(Rads);
  Tmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Tmp.TransparentColor := Bmp.TransparentColor;
    Tmp.TransparentMode := Bmp.TransparentMode;
    Tmp.Transparent := Bmp.Transparent;
    Tmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := BkColor;
    if AdjustSize then
    begin
      Tmp.Width := Round(Bmp.Width * Abs(C) + Bmp.Height * Abs(S));
      Tmp.Height := Round(Bmp.Width * Abs(S) + Bmp.Height * Abs(C));
      OffsetX := (Tmp.Width - Bmp.Width * C + Bmp.Height * S) / 2;
      OffsetY := (Tmp.Height - Bmp.Width * S - Bmp.Height * C) / 2;
    end
    else
    begin
      Tmp.Width := Bmp.Width;
      Tmp.Height := Bmp.Height;
      OffsetX := (Bmp.Width - Bmp.Width * C + Bmp.Height * S) / 2;
      OffsetY := (Bmp.Height - Bmp.Width * S - Bmp.Height * C) / 2;
    end;
    Points[0].X := Round(OffsetX);
    Points[0].Y := Round(OffsetY);
    Points[1].X := Round(OffsetX + Bmp.Width * C);
    Points[1].Y := Round(OffsetY + Bmp.Width * S);
    Points[2].X := Round(OffsetX - Bmp.Height * S);
    Points[2].Y := Round(OffsetY + Bmp.Height * C);
    PlgBlt(Tmp.Canvas.Handle, Points, Bmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Bmp.Width,
      Bmp.Height, 0, 0, 0);
    Bmp.Assign(Tmp);
  finally
    Tmp.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure RotateBitmapGR32(Bmp: TBitmap32; Degs: Integer; AdjustSize: Boolean;
  BkColor: TColor = clNone; Transparent: Boolean = False); overload;
var
  Tmp: TBitmap32;
  Transformation: TAffineTransformation;
begin
  Tmp := TBitmap32.Create;
  Transformation := TAffineTransformation.Create;
  try
    Transformation.BeginUpdate;
    Transformation.SrcRect := FloatRect(0, 0, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height);
    Transformation.Translate(-0.5 * Bmp.Width, -0.5 * Bmp.Height);
    Transformation.Rotate(0, 0, -Degs);
    if AdjustSize then
      with Transformation.GetTransformedBounds do
        Tmp.SetSize(Round(Right - Left), Round(Bottom - Top))
    else
      Tmp.SetSize(Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height);
    Transformation.Translate(0.5 * Tmp.Width, 0.5 * Tmp.Height);
    Transformation.EndUpdate;
    Tmp.Clear(Color32(BkColor));
    if not Transparent then
      Bmp.DrawMode := dmTransparent;
    Transform(Tmp, Bmp, Transformation);
    Bmp.Assign(Tmp);
    Bmp.OuterColor := Color32(BkColor);
    if Transparent then
      Bmp.DrawMode := dmTransparent;
  finally
    Transformation.Free;
    Tmp.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure RotateBitmapGR32(Bmp: TBitmap; Degs: Integer; AdjustSize: Boolean;
  BkColor: TColor = clNone); overload;
var
  Tmp: TBitmap32;
  Transparent: Boolean;
begin
  Tmp := TBitmap32.Create;
  try
    Transparent := Bmp.Transparent;
    Tmp.Assign(Bmp);
    RotateBitmapGR32(Tmp, Degs, AdjustSize, BkColor, Transparent);
    Bmp.Assign(Tmp);
    if Transparent then
      Bmp.Transparent := True;
  finally
    Tmp.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure RotateBitmapGDIP(Bmp: TBitmap; Degs: Integer; AdjustSize: Boolean;
  BkColor: TColor = clNone);
var
  Tmp: TGPBitmap;
  Matrix: TGPMatrix;
  C: Single;
  S: Single;
  NewSize: TSize;
  Graphs: TGPGraphics;
  P: TGPPointF;
begin
  Tmp := TGPBitmap.Create(Bmp.Handle, Bmp.Palette);
  Matrix := TGPMatrix.Create;
  try
    Matrix.RotateAt(Degs, MakePoint(0.5 * Bmp.Width, 0.5 * Bmp.Height));
    if AdjustSize then
    begin
      C := Cos(DegToRad(Degs));
      S := Sin(DegToRad(Degs));
      NewSize.cx := Round(Bmp.Width * Abs(C) + Bmp.Height * Abs(S));
      NewSize.cy := Round(Bmp.Width * Abs(S) + Bmp.Height * Abs(C));
      Bmp.Width := NewSize.cx;
      Bmp.Height := NewSize.cy;
    end;
    Graphs := TGPGraphics.Create(Bmp.Canvas.Handle);
    try
      Graphs.Clear(ColorRefToARGB(ColorToRGB(BkColor)));
      Graphs.SetTransform(Matrix);
      Graphs.DrawImage(Tmp, (Cardinal(Bmp.Width) - Tmp.GetWidth) div 2,
        (Cardinal(Bmp.Height) - Tmp.GetHeight) div 2);
    finally
      Graphs.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Matrix.Free;
    Tmp.Free;
  end;
end;

{ TTestForm }

constructor TTestForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Font.Name := 'Tahoma';
  Top := 0;
  ClientWidth := 560;
  ClientHeight := 915;
  Show;
  FImage := TImage.Create(Self);
  FOpenDialog := TOpenDialog.Create(Self);
  FOpenDialog.Title := 'Select an small sized image (min. 100 x 100)';
  FOpenDialog.Options := FOpenDialog.Options + [ofFileMustExist];
  FOpenDialog.Filter := 'JPEG|*.JPG|BMP|*.BMP';
  if FOpenDialog.Execute then
  begin
    FImage.Picture.LoadFromFile(FOpenDialog.FileName);
    OnPaint := FormPaint;
    Invalidate;
  end
  else
    Application.Terminate;
end;

procedure TTestForm.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  Img: TBitmap;
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  Bmp32: TBitmap32;
  BkColor: TColor;
  AdjustSize: Boolean;
  Degs: Integer;
  Rads: Single;
  RotCount: Integer;
  I: Integer;
  Tick: Cardinal;
begin
  Img := TBitmap.Create;
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  Bmp32 := TBitmap32.Create;
  try
    BkColor := clBtnFace;
    Img.Canvas.Brush.Color := BkColor;
    Img.Width := 100;
    Img.Height := 100;
    Img.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, FImage.Picture.Graphic);
    AdjustSize := False;
    Degs := 45;
    Rads := DegToRad(Degs);
    RotCount := 1000;

    Canvas.TextOut(10, 10, 'Original:');
    Canvas.Draw(10, 30, Img);
    Canvas.TextOut(10, 140, Format('Size = %d x %d', [Img.Width, Img.Height]));
    Canvas.TextOut(10, 160, Format('Angle = %d°', [Degs]));
    Canvas.TextOut(10, 250, Format('%d rotations:', [RotCount]));

    Canvas.TextOut(120, 10, 'SetWorldTransform:');
    Bmp.Assign(Img);
    RotateBitmapSWT(Bmp, Rads, AdjustSize, BkColor);
    Canvas.Draw(120, 30, Bmp);
    if not AdjustSize then
    begin
      Tick := GetTickCount;
      for I := 0 to RotCount - 2 do
        RotateBitmapSWT(Bmp, Rads, AdjustSize, BkColor);
      Canvas.TextOut(120, 250, Format('%d msec', [GetTickCount - Tick]));
      Canvas.Draw(120, 140, Bmp);
    end;

    Canvas.TextOut(230, 10, 'PlgBlt:');
    Bmp.Assign(Img);
    RotateBitmapPLG(Bmp, Rads, AdjustSize, BkColor);
    Canvas.Draw(230, 30, Bmp);
    if not AdjustSize then
    begin
      Tick := GetTickCount;
      for I := 0 to RotCount - 2 do
        RotateBitmapPLG(Bmp, Rads, AdjustSize, BkColor);
      Canvas.TextOut(230, 250, Format('%d msec', [GetTickCount - Tick]));
      Canvas.Draw(230, 140, Bmp);
    end;

    Canvas.TextOut(340, 10, 'Graphics32:');
    Bmp.Assign(Img);
    RotateBitmapGR32(Bmp, Degs, AdjustSize, BkColor);
    Canvas.Draw(340, 30, Bmp);
    if not AdjustSize then
    begin
      Tick := GetTickCount;
      for I := 0 to RotCount - 2 do
        RotateBitmapGR32(Bmp, Degs, AdjustSize, BkColor);
      Canvas.TextOut(340, 250, Format('%d msec', [GetTickCount - Tick]));
      Canvas.Draw(340, 140, Bmp);

      // Without in between conversion to TBitmap:
      Bmp32.Assign(Img);
      Tick := GetTickCount;
      for I := 0 to RotCount - 1 do
        RotateBitmapGR32(Bmp32, Degs, AdjustSize, BkColor, False);
      Canvas.TextOut(340, 270, Format('%d msec (optimized)',
        [GetTickCount - Tick]));
    end;

    Canvas.TextOut(450, 10, 'GDI+ :');
    Bmp.Assign(Img);
    RotateBitmapGDIP(Bmp, Degs, AdjustSize, BkColor);
    Canvas.Draw(450, 30, Bmp);
    if not AdjustSize then
    begin
      Tick := GetTickCount;
      for I := 0 to RotCount - 2 do
        RotateBitmapGDIP(Bmp, Degs, AdjustSize, BkColor);
      Canvas.TextOut(450, 250, Format('%d msec', [GetTickCount - Tick]));
      Canvas.Draw(450, 140, Bmp);
    end;
  finally
    Bmp32.Free;
    Bmp.Free;
    Img.Free;
    OnPaint := nil;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Now looking at [`this library`](http://www.crossgl.com/aggpas/) internals, it could also be one of the hot favorites for this benchmark... And also the results of antialiasing [`looks impressive`](http://www.antigrain.com/doc/introduction/introduction.agdoc.html#toc0005) (I have to try it :-)

Comment: @TLama - Hi TLama, What are the conclusions with that library? The 'rotate' is it better (smooth, fast) than the code above? Thanks.

Comment: @Altar, sorry, I forgot on this. The output of AGG is great (I'm using it for every vector rendering I do). If will be faster than the above ways I don't know though.

Comment: @Altar No problem here in XE2 with `uses Winapi.GDIPAPI`.

Comment: This is great! Thanks. But when I tried using SetWorldTransform I had some problems. When I rotated image for Pi/2 rad (90 deg) the bottom half of image was cut off. So I just used PlgBlt. I didn't want to use additional libs.

Comment: I implemented the SetWorldTransform variant. It seems to contain a small bug. The 'size' parameter passed to BitBlt must be the source size (Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height), not the destination size (Tmp.Width, Tmp.Height). The code works as is, but it truncates some parts of the image during the process, when the image is not a square.

The correct call is:

    BitBlt(Tmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height, Bmp.Canvas.Handle,
      0, 0, SRCCOPY);

Comment: I also implemented the PlgBlt variant. It works like a charm.

Comment: I see a black rectangle around the image when I use JanFX or Gr32:  http://imgur.com/a/B6k39

Comment: also some quality/speed comparison (set world transform quality is very bad): http://imgur.com/a/7GahN

Comment: Note: All functions except GDI+ are without antialiasing!

Comment: Did anyone managed to keep the rotated image centered (when AdjustSize= true)?

Answer (score 2):

If someone is looking into image rotation, they might also take a look at the Mitov video library (free for non-commercial use: [link](http://www.mitov.com/products/videolab#overview)). VCL and FireMonkey. It takes care of all the low-level details, which lets us avoid the kind of detailed coding that NGLN's excellent answer explores.

We've been using it for the past two years and have been *very* happy with it in our commercial app.

It has a rotate component that works with static images and video streams. Their library is fully-multi-tasking, optionally using all the cores and low level primitives available, on Intel chipsets with Intel's own performance library ([http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-ipp](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-ipp/))

On moderate hardware we can run multiple video or bmp streams which we rotate, clip, scale, and process at the pixel level, in real-time.