# How to "flush" changes to a bitmap's ScanLine

Tags: delphi, bitmap, vcl, delphi-2007, scanline

I'm currently trying to add mirroring to our RotateBitmap routine (from http://www.efg2.com/Lab/ImageProcessing/RotateScanline.htm). This currently looks like this (BitMapRotated is a TBitmap) in pseudo-code:

```
var
  RowRotatedQ: pRGBquadArray; //4 bytes

if must reflect then
begin
  for each j do
  begin
    RowRotatedQ := BitmapRotated.Scanline[j];
    manipulate RowRotatedQ
  end;
end;

if must rotate then
begin
  BitmapRotated.SetSize(NewWidth, NewHeight); //resize it for rotation
  ...
end;
```

This works if I **either** must rotate **or** reflect. If I do both then apparently the call to `SetSize` invalidates my previous changes via ScanLine. How can I "flush" or save my changes? I tried calling `BitmapRotated.Handle`, `BitmapRotated.Dormant` and setting `BitmapRotated.Canvas.Pixels[0, 0]` but without luck.

**Edit:** I found the **real** issue - I'm overwriting my changes with values from the original bitmap. Sorry for the effort.

Comment: why not using readymade libs like Graphics32.org or Vampyre Imaging?

Comment: I would simply have an output bitmap. Anyway, [`this Q&A`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10633410/960757) might be interesting for your task.

Comment: @Arioch'The: We're already using this routine and it seemed like an easy task to extend it.

Comment: @TLama: IIUYC `BitmapRotated` already **is** the output bitmap. The routine is declared `procedure RotateBitmap(
  const BitmapOriginal: TBitmap; // input bitmap (possibly converted)
  const BitMapRotated: TBitmap; // output bitmap
  ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is not really an answer, but this code works in both D2006 and XE3 and gives the expected result. There is no need to 'flush' anything.

[image]

```
  procedure RotateBitmap(const BitMapRotated: TBitmap);
  type
    PRGBQuadArray = ^TRGBQuadArray;
    TRGBQuadArray = array [Byte] of TRGBQuad;
  var
    RowRotatedQ: PRGBQuadArray;
    t: TRGBQuad;
    ix, iy: Integer;
  begin
    //first step
    for iy := 0 to BitMapRotated.Height - 1 do begin
      RowRotatedQ := BitMapRotated.Scanline[iy];
     // make vertical mirror
      for ix := 0 to BitMapRotated.Width div 2 - 1 do begin
        t := RowRotatedQ[ix];
        RowRotatedQ[ix] := RowRotatedQ[BitMapRotated.Width - ix - 1];
        RowRotatedQ[BitMapRotated.Width - ix - 1] := t;
      end;
    end;

    //second step
    BitMapRotated.SetSize(BitMapRotated.Width  + 50, BitMapRotated.Height + 50);
    //some coloring instead of rotation
    for iy := 0 to BitMapRotated.Height div 10 do begin
      RowRotatedQ := BitMapRotated.Scanline[iy];
      for ix := 0 to BitMapRotated.Width - 1 do
        RowRotatedQ[ix].rgbRed := 0;
    end;
  end;

var
  a, b: TBitmap;
begin
  a := TBitmap.Create;
  a.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  a.SetSize(100, 100);
  a.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
  a.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, 50, 50));
  b := TBitmap.Create;
  b.Assign(a);
  RotateBitmap(b);
  Canvas.Draw(0, 0, a);
  Canvas.Draw(110, 0, b);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll check on monday. Probably my issue is somewhere else than I think.