# Simple way to rotate image

Tags: pascal, lazarus, freepascal

Is there some simple way to rotate image by given angle?

I load image using TPortableNetworkGraphic and now I would like to rotate this e.g. for 11 degrees and draw on TPaintBox.

Could you help me?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633400/rotate-bitmap-by-real-angle ? However, I'm not sure the `alphachannel` in your `.png` will survive.

Comment: I used TBitmap32 from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633400/rotate-bitmap-by-real-angle